# "Launch a missile at" vs. "in" vs. "from"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct usage of ‘on’, ‘at’ and ‘in’ from a foreigner’s point of view](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/757/correct-usage-of-on-at-and-in-from-a-foreigners-point-of-view)

I don't know which of these three sentences is preferable:

> 1. India launched its Agni PSLV 5 missile **at** Chandipur, about 15 km from Balasore.
> 2. India launched its Agni PSLV 5 missile **in** Chandipur, about 15 km from Balasore.
> 3. India launched its Agni PSLV 5 missile **from** Chandipur, about 15 km from Balasore.

Comment: The use of *at* is ambiguous and might suggest Chandipur was the target; *from* is an alternative.

Comment: Also related: [#17440](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17440/preposition-usage-on-in-and-at), [#33140](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33140/is-there-a-rule-in-preposition-using), etc.

Comment: And [there is a good answer on Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3077/18696) about how to frame this sort of question.

Comment: The sentence is not ambiguous because you fire a projectile _at_ a target.

Comment: Normally "launched at Chandipur" would be understood to mean that Chandipur was the target. But: "We considered which missile to use: the one at Chandipur or the one at Hanumangarh. Finally we decided to launch the missile at Chandipur." I think most readers would understand that to mean that the missile located at Chandipur was launched, not that the missile was aimed at Chandipur. That's why "at" is a poor choice in context: it could be ambiguous.

Comment: Since we don't know what you're trying to say, how can we know which of those three statements best expresses it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am trying to say that the missile was launched from a place and not mean that Chandipur was the target.

Comment: @Sudhir: In that case, 3 is the most natural. 2 is okay. 1 is all wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) India launched its Agni PSLV 5 missile at Chandipur,about 15 km from Balasore.

This results in a missile hitting Chandipur.

> 2) India launched its Agni PSLV 5 missile in Chandipur,about 15 km from Balasore.
>
> 3) India launched its Agni PSLV 5 missile from Chandipur,about 15 km from Balasore.

India launched the missile from a place called Chandipur.

Answer (score 3):

In OP's context, *"at"* is ambiguous - it could either mean *"located at"* or *"fired towards"*. If you didn't know Chandipur was [the location of the Indian Army's Integrated Test Range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandipur,_Orissa), you might well assume that second (incorrect) meaning.

Both *"in"* and *"from"* are equally valid, and unambiguously specify *where the launch took place*. Arguably *"in"* more strongly implies that the missile was "long-term based" in Chandipur, where *"from"* admits more of the possibility that it was transported there specifically for the purpose of being launched *from that location*.

Comment: To me, "in" sounds as though the missile was both launched in and landed in Chandipur; "from" sounds as though it was launched in Chandipur and landed somewhere else.

Comment: @alcas: That's because you strongly associate the word "in" with the **launch**, and because no target is specified you assume there may not actually be one (they might have shot it straight up in the air as a test). But as my second paragraph says, you can also associate *"in"* more with the **missile** (this particular missile is the one [normally] *located in Chandipur*).

Answer (score 1):

Further to the other answers, it shows the importance of word order...

The phrase as quoted suggests Chandipur is the target:

> India launched its Agni PSLV 5 missile at Chandipur, about 15 km from
>   Balasore.

Whereas a slight reordering of the clauses has the opposite meaning, suggesting the launch place:

> At Chandipur, about 15 km from
>   Balasore, India launched its Agni PSLV 5 missile.

But in general `at` suggests the target, `from` the launch-point