# Semantics of "on" versus "in"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, in-on

Please help me in choosing the right preposition in this sentence:

> The returned values seem a bit confusing on/in its semantics,

Here I'm talking about returned values of a computer programming function, after reading its expected behaviour.

Which one should I use and what is the difference about using *in* or *on*?

Comment: Unrelated to your particular question, but the given sentence should also begin `The returned values seem...`.

Comment: You gave this question the tag 'early-modern-english'? Who were you planning on talking to like that?

Comment: You could use a more natural sounding adverb, semantically. "The return values might be confusing, semantically"

Answer (score 8):

Not all uses of prepositions can be predicted by meaning. There are very few prepositions in English and they have a lot of uses, so mostly preposition uses are arbitrary and governed by particular predicates (*look at, listen to, speak on, tired of,* etc).

That said, however, there **is** a very common spatial-dimension sense for many prepositions, including *in, on,* and *at*. As [Fillmore describes it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf) in his [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/FillmoreDeixisLectures.pdf):

> The preposition ***at*** is said to ascribe no particular dimensionality to the referent of its associated noun; the preposition ***on*** is said to ascribe to the referent of its head noun the property of being a line or a surface; and the preposition ***in*** is said to ascribe to the referent of its head noun the notion of a bounded two-dimensional or three-dimensional space.
>
> Consider phrases like *at the intersection, on the line, on the page, on the wall, in the city, in the kitchen*.
>
> Contrast
>
> - ***at** the corner,* which means near or in contact with the intersection of two straight lines, or streets
> - ***on** the corner,* which locates something as being in contact with part of the surface of some angular two-dimensional figure or three-dimensional object
> - ***in** the corner,* in which the noun *corner* is used to indicate a portion of three-dimensional space -- in particular, a part of the interior of, say, a room.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies but can you help me in the sentence above mentioned ?

Comment: What you mean by _semantics_ is up to you; it's gonna be a [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) anyway, but you get to pick the one you mean. That depends on whether you mean to imply that _semantics_ in this context is a **layer** (or some other 2-D meme), in which case _on_ is correct (and implies other layers); or whether you conceive of _semantics_ as **content** (or some other 3-D meme), in which case _in_ is correct because it refers to the container of the content.

Comment: @utxeee: I think you're getting a lot of help on the "sentence above mentioned." Short answer: "in" seems to be a better fit than "on." Long answer: We can't know for sure, because, collectively, we are having trouble understanding the meaning of the sentence (much like the returned values, it has confusing semantics).

Comment: In the context of the returned values of a function, it might be simpler merely to say they were unexpected, and then specify the parameters more precisely. If you have a precise specification available for what "semantics" means in this context, use it. It will most likely refer either to a **document** (a 2-D metaphor) or its **contents** (3-D).

Answer (score 4):

Without context, I'm not sure what the sentence means, but it would have to be *in their semantics* (*their* because *values* is plural).

Comment: I'm not sure values have semantics.  Perhaps OP means the semantics of the function, in which case the whole sentence needs to be recast.

Answer (score 2):

Can you restructure your sentence?

> The semantics of the return values are confusing

or,

> The return values have confusing semantics

Comment: Thanks all for your replies but can you help me in the sentence above mentioned ?