# Which preposition should be used when referring to an exact date?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I read this in a text book:

> My test is on 22th of June.

I saw this in a YouTube tutorial:

> My test is at 22th of June.

Which sentence uses the right preposition?

Comment: First one. and I prefer you say on _the_ 22nd of June - notice the _the_ and the _nd_ ending of the 22nd

Comment: @mplungjan Essentially perfect answer. "At" in this case is about as fundamentally wrong as can be. OP, take note of the correction to "22nd," too, not "22th."

Comment: Usage of _at/in/on_ fits in a metaphoric frame, as described [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/71574/15299).

Comment: Since when does Youtube trump text-books re:English language? - That's the important question here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A variation of your first sentence:

> My test is on the 22nd of June.

Although you may write on June 22, 2013, in a conversation I would say on *the* 22nd of June - notice the *the* and the nd ending of the 22nd. Alternatively you can say *on June 22nd*.

More here [In, At, On + Time or Date](http://www.5minuteenglish.com/mar18.htm)

> - in + month or year - *in March, in 2013*
> - on + date (with the year or without it) or day of the week - *on April 2, on March 3, 2014, on Saturday*
> - at + clock time, midnight, noon - *at 3:30 p.m., at 4:01, at noon*
>
> Remember also...
>
> - in + season - *in the summer, in the winter*
> - in + morning, afternoon, evening - *in the morning, in the evening*
> - at + night - *at night*

Comment: ...or 22nd June (without _the_ and _of_).

Comment: Then I would say _on June 22nd_

Comment: ... which differs between AE and BE.

Comment: Which do which? Impossible to do a proper nGram on this. Tried with 1st of April, April 1st and 1st April...

Comment: @mplungjan BrE generally uses day-month-year: *22nd [of] June* as in your first example.

Comment: Ok I'll take your word for it :)

Comment: TrevorD, you're right. mplungjan, saying *June 22nd* is typically American. DavidR, not including *the* and *of* is part of American English and not British.

Comment: What about June 22, 9am?What preposition should be put in exact date with time?

Comment: My test is on _the 22nd of June at 9am_ or _the 22nd of June at 9 in the morning_

Answer (score -1):

A precise date always takes “on”