# Why is it on the spot ( as in put someone on the spot), but in a tough/ tight spot ?

Tags: prepositions

Why isn't the preposition "on" used in both cases?

Comment: No particular reason.

Comment: That's what I thought

Comment: Possible duplicate of “[Semantics of ‘on’ versus ‘in’](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/71554/14073)”.

Comment: @Clare are incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semantics of "on" versus "in"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71554/semantics-of-on-versus-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're different metaphors.

"On the spot" has two meanings, being at an important place when something happened/is happening and being put in a (generally difficult) position of having to deal with something.

The second of those two meanings (which is the one you reference) is based on the first. In the first "the spot" is literally the place where you are standing (sitting, running screaming in a panic, whatever), and you are literally on it. As someone "on the spot" in this sense you are suddenly put in the position of having to act quickly, so by extension the second meaning refers to this figuratively, solely about being put in the position of having to act quickly.

The *tight spot* phrase is also a metaphor of space and position. Here though consider being in a place that is literally tight ("in a tight place" and "in a tight corner" are other variants). You are restricted in movement and action. *In* is the preposition we would use for that literal position, so its what we use in a figurative use too.

The vagueness of *spot* in terms of places (it can be used, especially if we include colloquial and slang usages, for anything from an exact location one might be at, to a premises, to a part of town or larger again) lets it be used in expressions where different prepositions make the most sense.

Comment: That was the nudge I needed to really grasp it. Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly enough, there's a purely idiomatic use of "on the spot" which means "did it right then and there, without delay."   The meaning you and the OP refer to I suspect refers to being placed at a putative target location, or less fatally at the location onstage where the main spotlight is.  But either way, it means to be at a critical location when something important is/must happen.  cf "Johnny on the spot"

Comment: I thought putting someone on the spot represented something you'd see in court trials or hearings. The opposing side would put witnesses under the third degree in leading questions, or treat them as hostile witnesses, so I can see how putting someone in a tight spot would make that person feel uncomfortable. I thought it was similar to putting someone on the stand.

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony I'm not aware of *spot* being used as court jargon. Can you point to that?

Answer (score 1):

Preposition exist to situate the reader relative to nouns (thing) or actions (verb). (Example: The rifle ABOVE the fireplace fell ON the mantle during the earthquake.)  The use of prepositions is idiomatic. The best way to understand the differences in their use is to analyze the meanings of the phrase. The phrase "on the spot" means people are in an uncomfortable position, like a stage, and all attention is on them. Would you say put someone "in the stage" or "on the stage"? As for "in a tight spot", what you mean is, they are in a position of danger. Would you say, "Help, he's on danger?" or "Help, he's in danger?"

Comment: Yes. There is more about how prepositions sometimes obey spatial dimensions in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/71574/14073) by John Lawler.

Answer (score 0):

The literal meaning of “in a tight spot” is a physical location where there are significant constraints on movement. When it’s used metaphorically, the preposition remains the same, as it is still evoking the sense of being surrounded by constraints.  The literal meaning of “on the spot” is that there’s a particular location that is the focus of attention. So, for instance, in Wheel of Fortune there’s a spot marked on the floor for the contestant to stand while trying to complete the final puzzle. The contestant is literally “on the spot”.