# Prof Doe in/at the Department of, in/at the Faculty of, at/in the University of

Tags: prepositions

I am reviewing an edited document in which the editor changed

> Prof Doe **in** the Department of ... **in** the Faculty of ... at the University of ...

to

> Prof Doe **at** the Department of ... **at** the Faculty of ... at the University of ...

I'm pretty sure I'm right, but I don't want to make arbitrary corrections.

[Use of capitals for names of departments and faculties, and dropping the full stop from Prof not at issue — these are all house style]

Comment: I think it's correct all through.

Comment: Related [correct usage of on, at, and in from a foreigner's point-of-view](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/757/correct-usage-of-on-at-and-in-from-a-foreigners-point-of-view)

Answer (score 6):

I like your version better than your editor’s. In particular I dislike “at the Faculty”— unlike a University, a Faculty doesn't serve double duty as both an institution and a place. The Department is a group of people within a larger group of people who are all at the place.

(In US usage, Prof Doe is ***on*** the Faculty; but here the syntax implies that it is the Department which is related to the Faculty.)

However, I suggest one change: *Prof Doe **of** the Department ...* Being ***in*** the Department suggests that Prof Doe is merely a minor piece, a cog in the machine—which of course may be the case, but if so should not be acknowledged. ***Of*** the Department sounds much grander, like **Arnold of Rugby** or **Lawrence of Arabia**—the *illustrious* Prof Doe, distinguishable from other Profs Doe, unknown and unsung.

(But if his title is grander, this would not be appropriate; you postpose the title:

> *John Doe, Egregious Professor of Whatsis **in** the Department of Whosis, Faculty of Whatever at the University of Wherever.*)

Answer (score 3):

There are many meanings and uses for both of these prepositions, some logical, some idiomatic.

In the uses you ask about, I think the following meanings are most helpful

The first meaning in the [COED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/in?q=in) for *in* is

> expressing the situation of something that is or appears to be enclosed or surrounded by something else:

In that same [reference](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/at), *at* is defined as

> expressing location or arrival in a particular place or position:

Both *in* and *at* are used to denote location, and the choice of which may be logical, but is often idiomatic. *In the street* but *at the corner of Hollywood and Vine*.

However *in* can be used non-geographically to convey being a part of something (*in* an organization), as well as literally in the middle of something (*in* a crowd). The preposition *at* is much more specifically physically locational (although it has other meanings relating to time and measurement).

In your examples, Department and Faculty convey a group or organization of which the subject is a part, rather than a physical location. As such,when used with Faculty,  *in* seems better, and *at* would jar (at least in US usage). Department is a bit less clear, perhaps because it is often associated with a particular location. Either could be used, but I think *in* would be strongly favored, again in US usage.

> He works in the Department of Defense [*yes*].
>   He works at the Department of Defense [*yes*].
>   He works in the History Department [*yes*].
>   He works at the History Department [*perhaps*].
>   He is enrolled at the History Department [*no*].

University, on the other hand, is both an organization and a physical place. While both *in* and *at* seem correct, I would probably favor *at*, if for no other reason than avoiding repetition.

Answer (score 2):

"In the faculty" is correct usage.

Both "at the department" and "in the department" are valid.

"at the University" is the correct usage.