# In or at the department of English and American Studies?

Tags: prepositions

Which of these preposition ( in or at) is correctly used with the noun department?

Is it correct to say: I was one of the interviewees in the department of English and American studies at the University of X for a position...?

Comment: Either is correct here, but see *[“Studying PhD at the university” or “studying PhD in the university”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7382)* (and its duplicate, *[Prof Doe in/at the Department of, in/at the Faculty of, at/in the University of](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103946)* ).

Answer (score 2):

Neither seems quite right to me. I'd probably re-organise your sentence thus:

> I was one of the interviewees for a position in the department of English and American studies at the University of X.

Answer (score 0):

"At the department" is used when talking about the department as an institution, "in the department" is when referring to it as a place.

There is a conference at the Department of English.
There was a fire in the Department of English.