# Grammar "at" or "in"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I wish to send my personal statement to a university and I had a problem writing it.

I wanted to know if I should use "in the Lally School of Management" or "at the Lally School of Management"?

Which one should I use *in* or *at*?

Text:

> In this regard, I hope that with the guidance of reputable professors in the Lally School of Management, I will strengthen my research capabilities and achieve my academic goals.

Comment: Compare [in/at university](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7382/studying-phd-at-the-university-or-studying-phd-in-the-university), [in/at department](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240673/in-or-at-the-department-of-english-and-american-studies). To some extent, it depends if you view the School as a place, building, or abstract entity, but in this case I don't have a strong preference.

Comment: So both of them can be true ?

Comment: In this regard 'in' is wholly unidiomatic. 'At' would be the usual choice.

At the same time I, for one, am sure the only way to avoid 'the guidance of reputable professors' being seen as patronising and arrogant would be to rely on the leeway allowed to non-native speakers.