# in/on/at the square

Tags: prepositions, in-on, at-on

Every time I see a different preposition for the word *square*, I wonder whether I do not understand it or there is a mistake.

> On 10 October [1939] they gathered everyone on the brewery square, which belonged to Mr Tejla.

Looking it up in dictionaries I found that *square* mostly collocates with ***in*** in terms of BrE. When it comes to AmE it's ***on***. How about *at*, which also refers to place but not specific?

Comment: Some nouns take several prepositions. Square is one. For me, an AmE speaker, *on the square* is the least likely choice to use. Nevertheless, I would use it if that were the nuance I was going for.

Comment: Just to confuse things, there is also "out of square".

Comment: (I'm thinking this question appeared a few months ago.)

Comment: It's a metaphor thing. _On_ refers to a 2-dimensional space (_on the lawn_) and _in_ to a 3-dimensional space (_in the yard_); surprisingly, _yard_ is 3-dimensional, while _lawn_ is 2-. It's explained [here, for instance](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/71574/15299), as well as [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/199115/15299)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Robusto's comment. As a BrE speaker, I'd use "in the square" to refer to a location.

I'd say *on the square* when I meant "at right angles to [something], or "honest". This is a reference to measuring an angle with a "square", and is/was used by Freemasons to refer to each other, [and has entered the language more generally.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_square)

> On the Square
>
> Adjective
>
> i) (idiomatic) Honest and open.
>
> ii) A discreet, unassuming reference to freemasonry.
>
> Usage notes
>
> This phrase is associated with Freemasonry: The angle measures the
>    square, 
>   the symbol of earth and the realm of the material. The square
>   represents fairness, balance, and firmness which is reflected in phrases
>   such as "on the square" and "squared away." Something that is squared
>   is something that is stable, a foundation for building upon.

Wiktionary

Answer (score 1):

As an AmE speaker I would use "in the square." But I would also say, "Let's meet on the quad."

Answer (score -2):

On the square as it is an open space

Comment: Ahmed, at EL&U we're looking for *authoritative* answers supported by evidence (e.g. references or links), rather than answers that are essentially unsupported personal opinion. For guidance, please read [answer] and take our [Tour]. :-)

Comment: ... [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71554/semantics-of-on-versus-in/71574#71574) by Professor John Lawler, which gives an attributed linked reference to a paper on the subject, is what would be considered a good one.