# "in" vs "on" vs "at" with "rarely used code paths"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of these alternatives is the best one?

- Bugs are often found **on** rarely used code paths
- Bugs are often found **in** rarely used code paths
- Bugs are often found **at** rarely used code paths

I have a hunch that either **on** or **in** are most appropriate but I have no idea which one to use here. A path is something you can stand on top of but a code section is something that the bugs can be inside of.

Comment: You don't need the word "path" at all.  Bugs are found soonest (e.g. by QA) in code that is executed often; bugs often remain undetected by QA in rarely executed code, and are thus often discovered by users in rarely executed code.

Comment: What about **around**, **about**, **among** or **between**? Any preposition would make grammatical sense here. It's whatever you stylistically feel like using.

Comment: *On* or *in* would work.  If you strike "paths," use *in.*  *At* would work if you rephrase ("...rarely executed points in the code" or the like).

Comment: @Tim Romano: My intention was to distinguish "rarely used code paths" from "rarely used code lines". Its possible for a test to have 100% line coverage but still not test every possible execution trace.

Comment: I'm going to strike a dissenting note, here, and cast a vote for leaving "paths."  Sometimes bugs are found (usually by customers) in code that is executed often.  When that well-trodden code segment is executed in a standard or usual way, it causes no trouble.  It's when it's part of an unusual path that it's a problem.  Bugs are found idiomatically *in* code.

Comment: @TimRomano Bugs are found by QA!  That's adorable.  Really.

Comment: Often  bugs are found by users on untested code paths.

Comment: Everything depends on how the "code paths" are metaphorized and examined. [There are at least three varieties](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/199115/15299) depending on the metaphrical topography and topology, and they produce _in, at,_ and _on_.

Comment: Or bugs are found by the technical writer who is tasked with making a User Manual for an app, documenting it with no trail of written specifications to refer to.

Comment: Either of the first two.  And I disagree with Tim -- using "path" is appropriate in some, perhaps most, circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that (computer) bugs are always *found* **in** things, whether those things be "code" or "paths".  If they were **on** (that is, external to) things, that would imply that they should in some way be obvious.