# What is correct? 'At d/m/y hh:mm' or 'On d/m/y hh:mm'

Tags: prepositions, time, dates

What is correct, if I want to be specific?

1. On 12/7/2015 12:35 I made a purchase
2. At 12/7/2015 12:35 I made a purchase

Comment: It's another case of dimensionality; _at_ exact times (_10:43, noon Saturday_), _on_ days (_Tuesday, the first of the month_), _in_ parts of a day (_the morning_ -- but _at night_ is an exception) and larger time units (_the 18th century, 23 years, only two weeks/months_). Basically, it's just a metaphor of the way it works for space, [as Fillmore points out](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/199115/15299). The larger durations are conceived of as volumes (3-D), the smaller as points on a line (1-D), and the medium-sized as areas (2-D), and the prepositions follow.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is _at night_ really an exception? Isn't it just that parts of the day take _at_ when there's no article and _in_ when there is? Thus _at dawn/noon/high tide/night/etc._, but _in the dawn/night/etc._

Comment: @Janus: _At night_ refers to a period (the dark part of the cycle), but it uses _at_ instead of _in_. _In the night/daytime/light of day_ are normal, but _at night_ isn't. I don't know any reason for it so I marked it as an exception. The _at_'s you mention  (_dawn_ and _high tide_) are both exact times rather than a time period like _night_. Ditto _at nightfall_ and _at twilight_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I would definitely consider _at dawn_ and _at nightfall_ to refer to periods, not exact times. They're shorter periods than _at night_ (or _at day_, though that's highly archaic), but not exact times. _High tide_ is so old-fashioned outside its literal sense that I don't rightly know if it's a point or a period.

Comment: But _We attacked at dawn_ means a specific time, whereas _We attacked at night_ merely distinguishes a dark duration containing the attack. Dawn and high tide are both inflection points; night is half the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 12:35, on 12/7/2015, I made a purchase.

'***At***' is used for specific times.

Comment: No need to reverse them, though: nothing wrong with “On 12/7/2015 at 12:35, I made a purchase”.

Comment: The comma after your 'them' is unnecessary.

Comment: Arguably unnecessary, but in no way incorrect; just a matter of style. Same goes for the comma after the date-time expression as well as both commas in your answer—they could all be left out without anything being actually mispunctuated.

Comment: Parentheticals are a choice as well. Yes?