# a or the in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

There is a reading exercise in this book I am using to teach. It goes ...

> A: Excuse me, is there a post office near here?
>   B: Yes. There's post office in Jindrisska Street. Turn right a the traffic lights. It's a big building on a corner.

My question is whether there should be a or the in the last sentence: *It's a big building* or *It's the big building*?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. The *on/at* question is answered by one of our resident professors of English at https://english.stackexchange.com/a/199115/18696.

Comment: I cannot see how the other question answered my question.....

Comment: In that case you need to edit your question to say why it doesn't. The other answers show that *the* references a specific object ("the big building") and *a* references one of a set of similar objects ("a big building"). If there is only one big building, it's that one; if there is more than one, it's one of them. Both *a* and *the* are equally valid, **grammatically** (so it could be either), but the choice helps define the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: well, your comment is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you