# Use of in and on

Tags: grammar

I'm having trouble when to use IN and ON. (i already know when to use it in a date and time)  Like in a plate or on a plate, in the floor or on the floor. Are there any rules about it?

Comment: What did your dictionaries and search engines leave out, please?

Answer (score 1):

For general concepts, see [Correct usage of ‘on’, ‘at’ and ‘in’ from a foreigner’s point of view](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/757/correct-usage-of-on-at-and-in-from-a-foreigner-s-point-of-view), especially the answer by John Lawler.

Applied to a *plate*, you usually put things *on a plate* because it's considered a surface. But if the plate was deep enough that it could be considered able to "enclose" the items/food you can use *in*, just like you would use *in* for a bowl.

As for *floor*, if you're talking about stuff (for example clothes) on the surface of the floor, use *on*. If you're talking about something "within" or "inside" the floor, like pipes or ducts, use *in*.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples
"On" - when it's about something laying **ON** the surface of something.
on the plate, on the floor
"In" means inside.
in the box, in the house