# Why do we use "at" in the phrase "good at [doing]"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions, compound-adjectives

In English, why do we use "at" in phrases such as "good at [doing something]", "terrible at [doing something]", etc.?

I'm trying to think of an example of how "at" is similarly used in other contexts, to shed light on this, but I'm coming up blank.

Comment: It's pretty thoroughly arbitrary. Certain prepositions go with certain words in certain phrases. They have to be learned as units; there isn't any "Why" to explain.

Comment: Keep at it. If you work at it long enough you’ll get it.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Could "at" in such contexts be called a "[specific location on a] **surface metaphor**"? Or is that stretching things a bit far? My main justification being that I'm increasingly becoming convinced that ***all** language is metaphor*, so it should be possible to classify just about everything as different *kinds* of metaphoric references.

Comment: There ***is*** a locative sense, though mostly _at_ is governed by individual lexical items. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/199115/15299) summarizes Fillmore's discussion, with links.

Answer (score 1):

Preposition at is often used in the following context:

> to show the activity in which someone's ability is being judged:
>
> - *I was never very good at sports.
>   He's very good at getting on with people.
>   She's hopeless at organizing things.*

but also

> to show the cause of something, especially a feeling:
>
> - *We were surprised at the news.
>   I was quite excited at the prospect.
>   Why does no one ever laugh at my jokes?*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Thanks for the additional example ("surprised at").